# MySQLi Update wont work but MySQL Works

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Why is it that when I try to run this function with MySQLi it will not work yet when I run it with MySQL it works fine? Ive tried PDO too :fname :new :id and all also. Is it because of the dynamic field name (column name)? Anyone know to resolve this with MySQLi? Thanks

```
function checkField($fname, $cur, $new, $id)
{
    echo $fname . ' '. $cur.' '. $new. ' '. $id . '<br/>';
    $id = (int) $id;

    if($new != $cur && is_string($new))
    {
        $fname = (string) $fname;
        $new = trim($new);
        $new = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $new);

        $query = "UPDATE coa0v_repinfo SET {$fname} = '{$new}' WHERE   id='{$id}'";
        mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: How does `$con` get into the function?

Comment: Why do you have braces around your variables? `{$fname}`

Comment: You would see with `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`...

Comment: `$query = printf("UPDATE coa0v_repinfo SET %s = '%s' WHERE   id=%d", $fname, $new, $id);`